# Who usually submits workshop proposals to conferences, and who usually pays for the workshop?

Tags: workshop

I just found that a prestigious conference has announced workshop proposal ([here](https://cci.drexel.edu/ieeebibm/bibm2016/BIBM16_WorkshopProposal.pdf)).

1. I would like to know who can send a proposal for workshops and from whom usually is the proposal accepted?
2. Does the conference pay for holding the workshop?

Answer (score 1):

1. Generally faculty or industry researchers propose workshops.
2. Workshops generally have an additional registration cost. From what I have seen, the conference pays for the workshop and coordinates a budget with the workshop but the money comes from that extra registration cost. I suspect that some larger workshops may not fit this model and may be entirely separate, but co-located.